# how to disable warning for niogroovymethods

Tags: java, groovy

I am using groovy-2.3.3, with jdk6u35. The groovy binaries have been extracted from groovy-sdk-2.3.3.zip.

After compiling with groovyc, I got an error while running java:

```
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0.
```

I googled and figured that the problem was with the groovy-all-2.3.3-indy.jar (which is used for jdk7+), so I removed it from my CLASSPATH. Now the program works, but it gives a warning:

```
WARNING: Module [groovy-all] - Unable to load extension class [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods]
```

How to disable this warning message, since I know that it is not applicable for my setup?

If I cannot disable this warning without a recompilation from source (which is not a valid option for me), is there any other groovy executable that I should download, instead of the sdk zip file, so that it can work with java-jdk6 without any warnings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before I got

```
➜~  groovy -version                          
Aug 6, 2014 12:29:38 PM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule newModule
WARNING: Module [groovy-nio] - Unable to load extension class [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods]
Groovy Version: 2.3.4 JVM: 1.6.0_45 Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. OS: Linux
```

Edit`vim $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/logging.properties`

Set INFO to SEVERE or OFF `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = SEVERE`

After

```
➜~  groovy -version                          
Groovy Version: 2.3.4 JVM: 1.6.0_45 Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. OS: Linux
```

UPDATE (Second better solution):

Remove groovy-nio-2.3.6.jar from lib folder

```
➜  ~  groovy --version
Aug 15, 2014 11:45:56 PM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule newModule
WARNING: Module [groovy-nio] - Unable to load extension class [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods]
Groovy Version: 2.3.6 JVM: 1.6.0_34 Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. OS: Linux
➜  ~  
➜  ~  mv $GROOVY_HOME/lib/groovy-nio-2.3.6.jar $GROOVY_HOME/lib/groovy-nio-2.3.6.bak
➜  ~  
➜  ~  groovy --version                                                              
Groovy Version: 2.3.6 JVM: 1.6.0_34 Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc. OS: Linux
```

Comment: Great!! Thanks. BTW, a couple of questions: (1) should the CLASSPATH be set to GROOVY_HOME/lib or embeddable? I noticed that if I set it to embeddable then I get the warning twice. What is the embeddable directory used for? (2) What did this warning about NioGroovyMethods mean?

Comment: With some research I found that indy stands for groovy with invoke dynamic support available from Java 7+ [link](http://groovy.codehaus.org/InvokeDynamic+support) I think you should not set classpath to lib folder as this jars are intended for groovy compiler/tools/... usage. 
You need Java 7+ to benefit from NioGroovyMethods moudule. See [link](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+2.3+release+notes#Groovy2.3releasenotes-NewNIOmoduleforJava7+)

Comment: In case anyone else is running into this problem after installing groovy with homebrew, run `brew info groovy` to get your GROOVY_HOME

Comment: Neither method is good for me as I am trying to distribute simple groovy script and have no access neither to JAVA_HOME nor GROOVY_HOME directories on a customer's machine. Really annoying. Better choose another language.